# how to copy an openframeworks example in xcode that has no xcodeproj

Tags: xcode, openframeworks

I'm trying to make a copy of the xmlSettings example in openframeworks from the examples > addons directory to do some testing, but it has no .xcodeproj file within it, so I'm not sure how to make a working example within xcode. I've used the project generator to generate empty projects, and I've copied projects that contain the xcodeproj file, but I've never had to deal with this scenario and I haven't had any luck finding a tutorial online. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even without the xcode project you should be able to use the ofxXmlSettings addon like so:

1. Right click the addons folder of your oF project, select **Add > Existing Files...** and select the ofxXmlSettings folder included in the oF/addons folder
2. Include the header file in your testApp.h file `#include "ofxXmlSettings.h"`
3. Use the addon:

in testApp.h declare an instance: `ofxXmlSettings xml;`
and use in `setup()` to load/save an xml file:

```
xml.clear();
xml.addTag("root");
xml.pushTag("root", 0);
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
    xml.addTag("child");
    xml.addAttribute("child", "id", (i+1), i);
}
xml.popTag();
xml.saveFile("test.xml");
```

Also if it helps, I've posted a zipped version of the sample xcode project [here](http://lifesine.eu/so/xmlSettingsExample.zip). Note that I'm using an older version of Xcode(3.2.6) on an older os(10.6.8), so not 100% it will work on your configuration.